# Альтернативы pyinstaller?

Tags: python

У меня возникают проблемы с компиляцией файла при помощи pyinstaller. Поэтому, как можно иначе сделать из .py .exe?

Comment: На винде лучше всего py2exe

Comment: Обычно pyinstaller справляется неплохо. А в чем собственно проблема? а так есть  cx_Freeze и  py2exe